# Statistics random variables

Tags: statistics

I'm having trouble with the following example:

If $a, b$ are functions of $\theta$ and $X\sim U(0,\theta)$, show that $Y=-\log(X)\sim E(a,b)$.

Comment: 1. You have not given any indication *where* you're having trouble. 2. $a$ and $b$ are not arbitrary functions of $\theta$... $-\log(X)$ has one and only one distribution so the goal must be to "*find* functions $a$ and $b$ such that ..." . Also $E(a,b)$ is not a standard notation. You should clarify that you mean some kind of exponential and what the parametrization is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] = \mathbb{P}[-\ln X \le y] = \mathbb{P}[X \ge e^{-y}] = 1 - F_X(e^y).
$$
Hence
$$
f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y) = -f_X(e^y) e^y.
$$
Can you substitute $f_X(y)$ and recognize in the final form what $a$ and $b$ have to become to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint: This is just the [inverse transformation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) on $F(y) = \exp(-y)$:

\begin{align}
P(Y \le y) &= F(y) = \exp(-y).
\end{align}

Since the cumulative distribution of $Y$ is exponential, by [Portemanteau Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), the density function of $Y$ is exponential.

Question: Why is $F(y) = \exp(-y)$ chosen?
Answre: Observe that the inverse function $F^{-1}$ encloses r.v. $X \sim \operatorname{unif}(0,\theta)$ in the proof of correctness of the linked wiki page.  Therefore, $F^{-1}(X) = -\log(X) = Y$, so $F(Y) = \exp(-Y)$.